# jQuery ajax Upload $_FILE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery plugin with $.ajax() functions.
There is some way to upload a file with POST and do some function when is it done?
here my code.... what i do wrong?

```
$.ajax({
                url: "../index.php?rqst=upload",
                type: 'POST',
                data:{
                    'fileToUpload': $("#fileToUpload").val()

                },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("file upload");
                }});
```

and this is the file input:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
```

and there is a way to display a gif during the load???
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

File uploads must be `enctype='multipart/form-data'` and you can't mix GET and POST like you're doing.  Since this is POST, remove the `?rqst=upload` from the url.  Also `$("#fileToUpload").val()` is only going to give you the name of the file, not the actual file.  You need a specialized javascript library to do file uploads with Ajax. Also, for a file upload, your input's type must be `type='file'` not `type='text'`.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to use $.post() than $.ajax().

You have it almost right. Instead of success use complete.

Just before running $.ajax(), add some simple dom manipulation code that puts a spinning gif somewhere. Then in the success callback handler add code to remove it.

Also, there is a javascript library for making spinning loading icons: http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/#!

Answer (score 1):

firstly i would check you are able to connect to the file directly,
comment out your data section and the change the url to a page holding an echo only.
then if the page can be found connected to you will get the alert.

on another note ensure "index.php?rqst=upload" has an echo in it so the success function picks it up. i usually use echos within if else statements so i can see if an error occurs and what error, then i can use the js to display the necessary message